# some readline lib missing for ruby on ubuntu 12.04 with rvm

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, readline

We are installing readline on ubuntu 12.04 for ruby 1.9.3. Some files are missing when running extconf:

```
$ ruby extconf.rb -- --with-readline-dir="$HOME/.rvm/usr"
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... no
checking for readline() in -ledit... no
checking for editline/readline.h... no
```

How do we install the last 3 files missed before running make install? Thanks so much.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920574/install-ruby-1-9-3-using-rvm-on-ubuntu), please. I think there is the same problem and it has solution.

Comment: The answer is only partial. No procedure about how to manually install libreadline5-dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download `libreadline5-dev` package for your architecture, for example, from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libreadline5-dev) and install install it manually.

```
sudo dpkg -i downloaded_package.deb
```

It should help you.

Comment: Still the same problem as listed above after installing libreadline5-dev. Here is the message (there is a warning about debhelper) : Unpacking libreadline5-dev (from libreadline5-dev_5.2-7build1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up libreadline5-dev (5.2-7build1) ...
Ignoring install-info called from maintainer script
The package libreadline5-dev should be rebuilt with new debhelper to get trigger support
Ignoring install-info called from maintainer script
The package libreadline5-dev should be rebuilt with new debhelper to get trigger support
Processing triggers for install-info ...

Comment: You can also try to install libreadline6-dev from repository.

Comment: Before libreadline5-dev, we need to install libncurses5-dev. That's why we are sticking with the 5 now.