# Rails Console command error in rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby1.9.3p327 and when I try to run the command "rails console" it returns the following error:

```
/home/humberto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in      `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
```

All the posts about this error propose the solution to uninstall and reinstall ruby, but that does not works for me. Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: readline isnt installed. try to find the requirements using 'rvm requirements' and install the readline package for rvm. see https://rvm.io/packages/readline/

Comment: this should be an answer

Comment: I've tried reinstalling rvm with the parametters of the readline as the link that surase sent, but it did not worked :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev libraries.
on ubuntu use: `sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev`
then reinstall ruby. i would recommend running `rvm cleanup all` before reinstalling ruby. just in case.

Also take a look to similar question with working answer. [install ruby 1.9.3 using rvm on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920574/install-ruby-1-9-3-using-rvm-on-ubuntu)