# no such file to load -- readline (Load Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, readline, libreadline

When I want to execute Rails 3 console, it throws this:

```
$ script/rails c
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (Load Error)
```

I tried to install `libreadline-dev`:

```
$ sudo wajig install libreadline-dev
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes extras:
  libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev
0 actualizados, 3 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 6 no actualizados.
Necesito descargar 1799kB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 7266kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar [S/n]? 
Des:1 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main libncurses5-dev 5.7+20090803-2ubuntu3 [1564kB]
Des:2 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main libreadline6-dev 6.1-1 [234kB]
Des:3 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main libreadline-dev 6.1-1 [904B]
Descargados 1799kB en 3seg. (477kB/s)
Seleccionando el paquete libncurses5-dev previamente no seleccionado.
(Leyendo la base de datos ...  00%
225006 ficheros y directorios instalados actualmente.)
Desempaquetando libncurses5-dev (de .../libncurses5-dev_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libreadline6-dev previamente no seleccionado.
Desempaquetando libreadline6-dev (de .../libreadline6-dev_6.1-1_i386.deb) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libreadline-dev previamente no seleccionado.
Desempaquetando libreadline-dev (de .../libreadline-dev_6.1-1_i386.deb) ...
Procesando disparadores para man-db ...
Procesando disparadores para install-info ...
Configurando libncurses5-dev (5.7+20090803-2ubuntu3) ...
Configurando libreadline6-dev (6.1-1) ...
Configurando libreadline-dev (6.1-1) ...
```

But when I tried again,it throws tha same again:

```
$ script/rails c
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:20:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Then, I try to install `readline` using `rvm`:

```
# rvm pkg install readline
Fetching readline-5.2.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives
Extracting readline-5.2.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/src
Applying patch '/usr/local/rvm/patches/readline-5.2/shobj-conf.patch'...
Configuring readline in /usr/local/rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Compiling readline in /usr/local/rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Installing readline to /usr/local/rvm/usr
Fetching readline-6.2.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives
Extracting readline-6.2.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/src
Applying patch '/usr/local/rvm/patches/readline-6.2/patch-shobj-conf.diff'...
Configuring readline in /usr/local/rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Compiling readline in /usr/local/rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Installing readline to /usr/local/rvm/usr
```

But again the same:

```
$ script/rails c
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:20:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What else should I try?

Comment: Note that you need not run `wajig` with sudo, since it does it automatically for you when needed. That is, just run `wajig install ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must check `rvm requirements` and ensure that all packages were installed.
Then reintall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.2
Removing /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p318...
Removing /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318...
Removing default ruby interpreter
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p318 aliases...
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p318 wrappers...
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p318 environments...
Removing ruby-1.9.2-p318 binaries...
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p318 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p318
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p318
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.18 for ruby-1.9.2-p318 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #importing default gemsets (/usr/local/rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #complete
```

And finally it works:

```
$ script/rails c
DEPRECATION WARNING: railtie_name is deprecated and has no effect. (called from <top (required)> at /home/israel/proyectos/d-Formacion/config/application.rb:7)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:98: warning: already initialized constant PDF
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.4)
1.9.2-p318 :001 > exit
```

Answer (score 6):

reinstalling ruby is kind of overkill, you can follow the instructions on this blog post.

http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby-on-rails/fixing-readline-for-the-ruby-on-rails-console

install libreadline5 and libncurses5

```
$ sudo aptitude install libreadline5-dev libncurses5-dev
```

then rebuild and reinstall redline

```
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p180/ext/readline
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  No need to reinstall Ruby!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The solution is combining the two steps:

1. Install libreadline-dev e.g. on an Ubuntu do:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
   ```
2. Reinstall Ruby

   ```
   rvm install 1.9.2
   ```

Then ruby will be compiled using libreadline.