# Unable to open the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Unable to open the rails console, throws the following error

```
$ rails c

/home/#/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require':   cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/#/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@aer-ui/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@aer-ui/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@aer-ui/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
from /home/#/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@aer-ui/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It is a known problem. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922700/ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3-cannot-open-rails-console

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the readline libraries installed when you compile Ruby.

Follow this blog:

[fixing-readline-for-the-ruby-on-rails-console](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby-on-rails/fixing-readline-for-the-ruby-on-rails-console/)